# How to scrape Facebook data using Graph API and the User Token?

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, web-scraping, social-media

I am trying scrape Facebook data, of public pages.

The code I was using a couple of months (10 months ago maybe) ago was working fine. Now, when I wanted to continue that project, but the code is not working anymore. I used to use my private user token, which expires after a couple of minutes. But it is enough for my use case. I don't need an App, and and App Review etc. to get a permanent token.

Here is the code:

```
def getData(page, urlToConnect, startTime, filterStart, filterEnd):

    posts = []
    found = False

    try:
        while (True):
            #print(url)
            facebook_connection = urlopen(urlToConnect)
            data = facebook_connection.read().decode('utf8')
            json_object = json.loads(data)
            #posts=json_object["data"]
            allposts=json_object["data"]
            allposts = np.asarray(allposts)
            created = startTime
            for i in range(0,100,1):
                if (pd.to_datetime(allposts[i]['created_time']) > pd.to_datetime(created)):
                    posts.append(allposts[i])
                else:
                    print(" found date at this index: ", i)
                    posts.append(allposts[i])
                    found = True
                    break;
                if (i == 99):
                    urlToConnect = json_object["paging"]["next"]
            if (found == True):
                break; 



        df=pd.DataFrame(allposts)

        df['Angry'] = df['Angry'].astype(str).str.replace('{\'data\':(.*?)count\': ','')
        df['Angry'] = df['Angry'].str.replace(',(.*?)}}','')

        df['Haha'] = df['Haha'].astype(str).str.replace('{\'data\':(.*?)count\': ','')
        df['Haha'] = df['Haha'].str.replace('}}','')

        df['Love'] = df['Love'].astype(str).str.replace('{\'data\':(.*?)count\': ','')
        df['Love'] = df['Love'].str.replace('}}','')

        df['Sad'] = df['Sad'].astype(str).str.replace('{\'data\':(.*?)count\': ','')
        df['Sad'] = df['Sad'].str.replace(',(.*?)}}','')

        df['Wow'] = df['Wow'].astype(str).str.replace('{\'data\':(.*?)count\': ','')
        df['Wow'] = df['Wow'].str.replace('}}','')

        df['comments'] = df['comments'].astype(str).str.replace('{\'data\':(.*?)count\': ','')
        df['comments'] = df['comments'].str.replace(',(.*?)}}','')

        df['likes'] = df['likes'].astype(str).str.replace('{\'(.*?)count\':','')
        df['likes'] = df['likes'].str.replace(',(.*?)}}','')

        df['shares'] = df['shares'].astype(str).str.replace('{\'count\': ','')
        df['shares'] = df['shares'].str.replace('}','')

        df['date'], df['time'] = df['created_time'].astype(str).str.split('T', 1).str
        df['time'] = df['time'].str.replace('[+]0000','')

        # Convert NaN's to 0 (as string)
        df['shares'] = df['shares'].str.replace('nan','0')
        df['shares'] = df['shares'].str.replace('Nan','0')
        df['shares'] = df['shares'].str.replace('NaN','0')

        # Convert Series values from str to int
        df['shares'] = df['shares'].astype(int)
        df['likes'] = df['likes'].astype(int)
        df['comments'] = df['comments'].astype(int)
        df['Love'] = df['Love'].astype(int)
        df['Wow'] = df['Wow'].astype(int)
        df['Sad'] = df['Sad'].astype(int)
        df['Angry'] = df['Angry'].astype(int)
        df['Haha'] = df['Haha'].astype(int)


        # Sum over all number columns of one row
        col_list= list(df)
        df['total_reac'] = df[col_list].sum(axis=1)

        # Sort values by 'total_reac' column, descending
        df = df.sort_values(by='total_reac', ascending=False)

        # Convert column from str to datetime
        df['created_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['created_time'])

        # Filter for dates needed
        df = df[(df['created_time'] > fStart) & (df['created_time'] <= fEnd)]


        # Save Dataframe as csv
        df.to_csv("Facebook_Posts_" + page + ".csv" )



    except Exception as ex:
        print (ex)

    return df



token="my_User__Token_Here (got from my personal  https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer)"

sTime = '2018-05-01'
fStart = '2018-05-01'
fEnd = '2018-05-29'


page_id="nytimes"

url="https://graph.facebook.com/3.2/"+page_id+"/posts/?fields=id,created_time,message,shares.summary(true).limit(0),comments.summary(true).limit(0),likes.summary(true),reactions.type(LOVE).limit(0).summary(total_count).as(Love),reactions.type(WOW).limit(0).summary(total_count).as(Wow),reactions.type(HAHA).limit(0).summary(total_count).as(Haha),reactions.type(SAD).limit(0).summary(1).as(Sad),reactions.type(ANGRY).limit(0).summary(1).as(Angry)&access_token="+token+"&limit=100"

dataNYT = getData(page_id, url, sTime, fStart, fEnd)


dataNYT.to_csv("NYT_posts.csv")
```

Here is the error I am getting now:

```
HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
```

And when I try to type in the url requested in my browser, this error appears:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Unknown path components: /nytimes/posts",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 2500,
      "fbtrace_id": "HsN9zi+byTD"
   }
}
```

Anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you get that error, when I try that API call in the API Explorer, i get the correct one:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#10) To use 'Page Public Content Access', your use of this endpoint must be reviewed and approved by Facebook. To submit this 'Page Public Content Access' feature for review please read our documentation on reviewable features: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 10,
    "fbtrace_id": "AZJ2HjKFmkW"
  }
}
```

You DO need an App, and you DO need App Review. In order to get access to pages you don´t own, you have to get "Page Public Content Access" approved by Facebook. After that, you can even use a never-expiring App Access Token. But you still need an App, for ANY API access, always.

More information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature/?locale=de_DE#reference-PAGES_ACCESS

Comment: But I used to do that a year ago, with that tiny piece of code, written in a python notebook. Did it change since May 2018?

Comment: a lot changed in the last year, you need to check out the changelog

Comment: Okay. So I have to develop a whole app to get info now..? :/

Comment: you must create an app on facebook, that´s the minimum for any api call. what you do after that depends on the use case. if you want to get access to public pages you don´t own, you have to show facebook somehow how you want to use the gained data. no data without approval.